# How to build model with 3D array label with TensorFlow

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, layer

I have data predictor in 2D array like this below

```
array([[   0,    0,    0, ...,   10,    6,    1],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,   12,    6,    1],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,    8,    6,    1],
       ...,
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,   54,   30,   60],
       [   0,    0,    0, ..., 1472,    5,  348],
       [   0,    0,    0, ...,   58,   45,   60]])
```

and label data with 3D shape like this below

```
[array([[0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
        [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32),
 array([[0., 0., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        ...,
...
        ...,
        [0., 1., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., ..., 0., 0., 0.]], dtype=float32),
 ...]
```

I would build the model with TensorFlow

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(total_words, 10, input_length=max_sequence_len))
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(total_words_label, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
```

But, I get error in latest Dense

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 10, 4991) and (None, 4991) are incompatible
```

It looks like from latest Dense shape because I have 3D label. How the way I can adjust it? I'm learning about TensorFlow.
And, how to convert the output to the 3D label when I have predict it?

--- update (adding the process) --

the example data

```
input                                        output/label
Hartford Avenue, Bellingham, MA, 2019    {'address': 'Hartford Avenue', 'city': 'Bellingham', 'state': 'MA','zip': '2019'}  
Oak Street, Brockton, MA, 2301           {'address': 'Oak Street', 'city': 'Brockton', 'state': 'MA', 'zip': '2301'}
```

the input is as predictor and the output/label is as label

The process of creating label

```
tokenizer_label = Tokenizer()
l = list(all['input'])

tokenizer_label.fit_on_texts(l)
total_words_label = len(tokenizer_label.word_index) + 1

labels = []
for i in range(len(l)):
    labels.append(keras_utils.to_categorical(tokenizer_label.texts_to_sequences(l[i].split()), num_classes=total_words_label))
```

Comment: How did you one-hot encode your labels?

Comment: I have label in a sentences, so I encode it in each word, 1 array represent 1 word, so it will be 2D-array label for a row data. Is there the correct way to encode my sentences label?

Comment: Each word is 10-dim vector?

Comment: yes, it's correct

Comment: can you show an example of your data and how you create your labels?

Comment: I have added the process in the post

Comment: you have a label per word or per sentence? (in other word, you classification has to be performed at each timestamp or only at the end of the whole sequence)

Comment: I have label in a sentences, so I encode it in each word, 1 array represent 1 word, so it will be 2D-array label for a row data.